# Combinatorial problem - coloured balls

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

I have balls with $n$ colors, $n ≥ 3$, and I want to put them into boxes.

1/ Each box must have at last 2 colors.

2/ For every pair of colors and for every color in that pair there is a box that contains that color and doesn't contain the other one, i.e. $\forall \mathrm{color1} \, \forall \mathrm{color2} ≠ \mathrm{color1} \, \exists \mathrm{box}:(\mathrm{color1} \in \mathrm{box} \land \mathrm{color2} \notin \mathrm{box}) $

Take the product of the number of balls in a box, over all the boxes. Call this $f(n)$. What is the minimum value of $f(n)$?

It is easy to see $f(2n) ≤ [f(n)]^2$

For instance, for any n, here is a possible division into boxes:
$\{1,2\},\{2,3\},...,\{n-1,n\},\{1,n\}$, so $f(n) ≤ 2^n$.

However one can do better. For $2n$ one can divide into boxes as follows:
$\{1,...,n\},\{n+1,...,2n\},\{1,n+1\},\{2,n+2\},...,\{n,2n\}$

so $f(2n) ≤ n^2 \cdot 2^n$

And I can do (somewhat) better than this. Basically I'm looking for an upper bound if it's low, or a lower bound if it's high - an exact formula isn't really needed.

Comment: The logical expression written in symbols does not express the same thing as the second condition written in text.

Comment: If we consider the condition written with natural language to be the correct one. Then that allows for a distribution such as ab, bc. This is wrong if we consider the logical expression to be correct, as there is no box that contains a and doesn't contain b.

Comment: I would rewrite the logical condition in the first case as: $\forall \mathrm{color1} \, \forall \mathrm{color2} ≠ \mathrm{color1} \, \exists \mathrm{box}:(\mathrm{color1} \in \mathrm{box} \land \mathrm{color2} \notin \mathrm{box}) \lor  (\mathrm{color2} \in \mathrm{box} \land \mathrm{color1} \notin \mathrm{box})$

Comment: In the second case, I would rewrite the sentence as: For every pair of colors and for every color in that pair there is a box that contains that color and doesn't contain the other one.

Comment: The logical expression is the correct one. I've rewritten the text per your suggestion. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem. By the way, do you know where this problem comes from?

Comment: It comes from a problem I'm working on in logic, so not from anything well known.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the values for $\{3,\dots,10\}$ are $8,16,32,64,128,240,384,768$.

Comment: @RobPratt. Calculated by brute force computation?

Comment: @RobPratt Can you share the code? I've been trying to brute force the first few values but I could not write something in polynomial time. Also, can you share the configurations that lead to $f(n)$ for $n \ge 8$?

Comment: @abo We can generalise the argument that you used for $f(2n) \le 2^n \cdot n^2$ to prove that $f(mn) \le m^n \cdot n^m$ for all $m,n \ge 2$. Which gives us a better bound for any composite number. This comment is too small for the proof but I can post it in an answer if you want.

Comment: @Oussema. That suffices for my purposes as a low enough upper bound, since then $f(n^2) ≤ n^n * n^n = n^{2n} << 2^{n^2}$. So please write as an answer.

Comment: I used integer linear programming, not brute force.  Here are some optimal solutions: \begin{align}n=8 &: \{1,3,4,6,7\}, \{2,3\}, \{2,7,8\}, \{1,5\}, \{6,8\}, \{4,5\} \\
n=9 &: \{1,3,4,5,7,9\}, \{2,3\}, \{2,9\}, \{5,6\}, \{4,8\}, \{7,8\}, \{1,6\} \\
n=10 &: \{1,6\}, \{3,7\}, \{2,10\}, \{1,7,8,10\}, \{4,5\}, \{4,9\}, \{2,3,5,6,8,9\}
\end{align}

Comment: @RobPratt Thank you! Do you recommend any resources for beginners to learn integer linear programming?

Comment: H.P. Williams, *Model Building in Mathematical Programming*.  The examples are solved with SAS [here](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=v_007&docsetId=ormpex&docsetTarget=titlepage.htm&locale=en).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's number the colors from $0$ to $mn - 1$.

We split the boxes into two categories:

The first category contains the following boxes:

$A_0:\{ 0, n, 2n,3n,...,(m-1)n \}$

$A_1:\{1,n+1,2n+1,...,(m-1)n+1\}$

$A_2:\{2,n+2,2n+2,3n+2,...,(m-1)n+2\}$

$\ldots$

$A_{n-1}:\{ n-1, 2n-1,3n-1,...,mn-1 \}$

The second category contains the boxes:

$B_0:\{0, 1,2,3,4,...,n-1\}$

$B_1:\{ n,n+1,n+2,...,2n-1 \}$

$\ldots$

$B_{m-1}:\{(m-1)n, (m-1)n+1,(m-1)n+2,...,mn-1\}$

If $n,m \ge 2$ then the first condition is satisfied.

Let's take two colors $c_1$ and $c_2$ whose Euclidian division by $n$ is $qn + r$ and $q'n + r'$ respectively.

The two colors are distinct so $q \neq q'$ or $r \neq r'$.

If $q \neq q'$ then $c_1 \in B_q$ and $c_2 \not\in B_q$.
If $r \neq r'$ then $c_1 \in A_r$ and $c_2 \not\in A_r$.

Either way, the second condition is satisfied.

The number of balls in each box in the first category is $m$ and there are $n$ boxes so the product is $m^n$.

The number of balls in each box in the second category is $n$ and there are $m$ boxes so the product is $n^m$.

As such, $f(mn) \le n^m \cdot m^n$ for all $m,n \ge 2$.